# How to run a php script using cron

Tags: php, cron

I have a php script that grabs links from another website. I am storing these links in my local system database using wamp server but my internet speed is so slow. I have to refresh the php script in browser after every 10 records.

So, can I run this PHP script on my webhosting server continuously for 24 hours and store all the links same as my local system. If it is possible then please help me.

Comment: Are you doing this from your local computer? What operating system are you running?

Comment: not what OS are YOU running but what OS is on the server that will be running the cron.

Comment: Yeah, as per @Bot ^ - is this a Linux server? (I'd missed that you want to transfer this to a remote host - have not re-paragraphed the question to make it easier to read!).

Comment: Does your webhosting server allow cron jobs? If yes, then it's possible. The cron command would look something like /usr/local/php/bin/php /home/site/path/to/script.php

Comment: Also note that a cron script will execute based on time, not number of records.

Comment: yes that is linux server

Comment: Duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/692208/how-to-run-a-php-script-in-cron?rq=1 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1972690/cannot-get-php-cron-script-to-run?rq=1

Comment: @way2project - ok thanks. As you can see, this is a direct duplicate of other questions here. Please always search here, and on a search engine, prior to asking questions `:)`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Type in `crontab -e` in the/a terminal or through PuTTy on your server, enter 
something to the like of the code below, where m is minutes, h is hours, dom 
is days of the month, etc etc etc

```
# m   h       dom     mon     dow     command
*/5   *       *       *       *       php -f /directory/to/file/filename.php
```

This will run it every five minutes.

If you want to run it continuously (which it doesn't really do), it needs to be run piece wise, something like this would work, which would run it from 9.30-17.30 every day.

```
30-59/5 9 * * * script.sh
*/5 10-16 * * * script.sh
0-30/5 17 * * * script.sh
```

Here are the basics of cron, I suggest you read them.

[Cron and Crontab](http://www.pantz.org/software/cron/croninfo.html)

Comment: but i want to run a script for 24 hours continously from any time. for example I want to start a script at 09:00 AM and want to run it for 24 hours Then how to do this

Comment: How long is the interval you want it to run? 5 minutes? 10? And I don't understand what you mean by run it for 24 hours? start at 9, and run until midnight?

Comment: actually this script stores the crawled links in the database and i want to store all links in one time only not by running the script daily. and i sure that all the links will store in 24 hours.So thats why i was asking.

Comment: So why not just run it every 5 minutes all day like the example above

Comment: Nice answer, +1. OP: yes, PHP background tasks are best running for a short while, rather than continuously. This is because PHP is prone to memory leaks; also, if it crashes, it will pick up where it left off on the next cron interval, rather than needing another system (or an admin) to restart it.

Comment: I agree, this should be ran in short sprint intervals (once every 5-10 minutes a few times a day) rather than running this consecutively. Upvoted halfer for a good point.