# How to run a php url with parameters in cron tab

Tags: php, linux, cron

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to run a php script in cron](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/692208/how-to-run-a-php-script-in-cron)

I have a php script that is set to run in cron.I want to run the url with passing one parameter. I tried to pass parameters as query string and put in crontab it didn't work. How to run a url with parameters using cron?

php /var/www/prod/Reports/report.php?email=sample@sample.com

Comment: you can try this `* * * * * curl "http://your_url/your_scripts?your_params"`, however, this is not ideal

Comment: Could any one tell why the question got rating down 2. is this not a valid question ?

Comment: @user1259132: You did not share any code, so it is not clear what you *are doing*. You did not share any error message, so it is not clear *what the problem is*. Won't work is not a question. The part of your question that is clear, *"How to run a url with parameters using cron?"* has been asked and answered before. Please use the search before asking a question, otherwise others might think you've done too less for clarifying your problem on your own and downvote you. See the tooltip when you hover the downvote button.

Comment: I searched a lot .. couldn't find anything related to cron with parameter passing.

Comment: simulating a http request via cron can be achieved by calling the desired web request from curl running inside cron php script

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ideally running PHP in command line interface (CLI) you would use $argv and $argc globals to pass parameters to the script.

Example: 
my_php_script.php

```
 <?
    var_dump($argv);


    php my_php_script.php arg1 arg2


array(3) {
  [0]=>
  string(17) "my_php_script.php"
  [1]=>
  string(4) "arg1"
  [2]=>
  string(4) "arg2"
}
```

Hari

Answer (score 6):

Show us your crontab (or at least the row with the PHP script). If you perform it like:

```
php script.php?param1=123
```

**The above will not work.** Instead do it like this:

```
wget http://localhost/script.php?param1=123&param2=345 -o /dev/null
```

Then it should work. If not, give more details.

Keep in mind, that the suggestion is JUST AN EXAMPLE. This would imply you have a running web server, that is configured to run PHP files, etc.

Comment: Yes , i tried php script.php?param1=123, it is not working

Comment: Yes Veseliq, The script works perfect without parameters :)

Comment: Did you read my answer at all?

Comment: I was telling everything configured well ( a running web server, that is configured to run PHP files, etc. )

Comment: `wget` is the simplest way to get the job done.

Answer (score 0):

Use the global [$argv](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.argv.php) to get command line parameters.