# Insert new row into table every minute with cron job

Tags: php, mysql, database, cron

I am trying to run a cron job every minute that will insert a new row into a specific table every minute.
I added the path to the ***feedUpdate.php*** file and `1 0 * * *` to execute it every minute. The ***feedUpdate.php*** looks like this:

```
<?php
require_once("../php_includes/db_conx.php");

$sql = "SELECT * FROM posts ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1"; //Select a random row from 'posts'
$query = mysqli_query($db_conx, $sql);
$row = mysqli_fetch_array($query, MYSQLI_ASSOC);
$id = $row['id']; //get the id of that specific random post selected
$sqlins = "INSERT INTO postfeed (postid, time) VALUES ('$id',now())"; //Insert the new post id into the feed table.
$queryins = mysqli_query($db_conx, $sqlins);
?>
```

This script works fine when I just write the path directly in the browser, but it doesn't run automatically every minute.

Any ideas why?

I am using 000webhost at the moment as it's free, but I know for a fact that it does run cron jobs as I have one that runs daily clearing temporary files.

Comment: Barmar here below is correct. Also have a look at the function `mysqli_fetch_assoc()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To run every minute, the cron job schedule should be `* * * * *`.

`1 0 * * *` means to execute every day at `00:01`.

Comment: ahh okay! I looked into it and it doesn't let me run it every minute, but it does let me run it every five minutes so I used */5 * * * * which should be correct, it has been 30 minutes and it still hasn't added any rows though... I just tested it by running it manually and there's nothing wrong with the code as it adds a row manually.

Comment: Check `/var/log/syslog` to see if it's reporting any errors when it tries to run it.

Answer (score 0):

```
*     *     *   *    *        command to be executed
-     -     -   -    -
|     |     |   |    |
|     |     |   |    +----- day of week (0 - 6) (Sunday=0)
|     |     |   +------- month (1 - 12)
|     |     +--------- day of        month (1 - 31)
|     +----------- hour (0 - 23)
+------------- min (0 - 59)
```

To run every minute try this:

```
* * * * * php /path/to/file/runScript.php
```

Stackoverflow: [How can I write a PHP cron script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26155160/how-can-i-write-a-php-cron-script)

Mirror: http://iswwwup.com/t/7cb7527ceffc/how-can-i-write-a-php-cron-script.html