# execute php file through cron job on aws amazon EC2 server

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I have database backup code in PHP file which i want to execute on daily basis. If i access that file through url then that executes successfully but i want to execute it through cron job daily.
If any one has experience about it then Please help me in this scenario.
Following is the path of file on server after SSH login:

```
/var/www/html/www/admin/db-backup.php
```

How to execute this file through cron.

Comment: Have you tried [to search on SF](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/692208/how-to-run-a-php-script-in-cron) or do you really need [doing it this way](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12893377/how-to-run-a-php-url-with-parameters-in-cron-tab)?

Comment: i have tried [to search on SF](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/692208/how-to-run-a-php-script-in-cron) through following command 
wget -O - http://domain.com/cron/script.php
can be  executed successfully but how to implement it in cron job.

Answer (score 4):

I have solved my problem in this way. 
1.connect server through SSH. 
2.command `crontab -e` 
3.After that press i to get in inser mode. 
4.`* * * * * /usr/bin/wget -O- http://domain.com/cronjob/yourscriptfile.php` 
5. Then press `esc` to exit insert mode then write `:wq` to save changes and press enter. 
Now your crontab has saved and your cron job will work successfully.