# How to run a php script automatically daily?

Tags: php, mysql, cron

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to run a php script in cron](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/692208/how-to-run-a-php-script-in-cron)

I need to run a php script at the scheduled time daily to update some fields in database and to send automated email. How I can do this?

Is it possible to write some service in XAMP server to run the script daily at scheduled time? I have no idea how to update database and send email automatically at the scheduled time. Can any one share some ideas or concepts?

I am using PHP and MySQL running in Linux Server.

Comment: i am almost hearing people typing answers as fast as possible.. :D

Comment: @doniyor, indeed. I spent more time overcoming the 30 character minimum. Vote to close.

Comment: I have the same question but I want a little more my script to do for me. I have a page where I update price automatically but it requires a button to be clicked to update price how can I do that? any solution?

Answer (score 6):

> Is it possible to write some service in XAMP server to run the script daily at scheduled time?

Create a [Cron Job](http://www.thesitewizard.com/general/set-cron-job.shtml).

Answer (score 3):

Look into CRON Jobs: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron They will allow you to schedule multiple scripts to run automatically, without your intervention on a determined schedule.

Answer (score 3):

you should use cron job, it will run your script automatically

http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2011/07/php-cron-job/