# How the WP-Automatic plugin works even it is not running on the cloud

Tags: php, wordpress, automation

There is a plugin for wordpress, WP-Automatic which fetches the RSS feed of other websites and create a post on our website, but how this works automatically. We are not running the plugin on cloud but it fetches the post from other website and add it. If we want to execute a PHP script the page must remain open or we may send a request to that page but there is nothing happening like that in this plugin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some weeks I found out It is done via CRON Jobs.
I figured it out from [How to run a php script automatically daily?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13313624/how-to-run-a-php-script-automatically-daily)

The WP-AUTOMATIC plugin runs at a fixed interval by CRON JOB and fetches the rss feed of other websites and then post it as an article.